# Getting a media file from resources

Tags: c#, reference, media, audio, system-sounds

I have added a notification sound for some text message as a reference of the Main file of my project and try to make it work as follows

```
System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream s = a.GetManifestResourceStream("SignInSound.wav");
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(s);
player.Play();
```

I have the sound played, but it is not absolutely the one I added. Instead standard windows sound is played. 
Any ideas?

**Update**

The issue is in getting the file from resources

```
System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream s = a.GetManifestResourceStream("SignInSound.wav");
```

Comment: (off-topic) you're not calling `s.Dispose()` in your example.

Comment: where should it be called and why?

Comment: When an object implements `IDisposable`, you should call its `Dispose()` method before the object goes out of scope. You have to do this, otherwise your app might start leaking memory. But again, all of that is missing the point.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas about the main point?

Comment: Not really. If the resource stream is bad, I would expect `player` to crash instead of playing something (seemingly) random. Can you identify the sound that is played back if not _SignInSound.wav_?

Comment: Hmm. A beep does typically indicate a warning or error. Perhaps `SoundPlayer` can't read the stream, but plays the error beep instead of displaying a message? That's my best guess.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), your resource stream is bad.

> The Play method plays the sound using a new thread. If you call Play
>   before the .wav file has been loaded into memory, the .wav file will
>   be loaded before playback starts. You can use the LoadAsync or Load
>   method to load the .wav file to memory in advance. After a .wav file
>   is successfully loaded from a Stream or URL, future calls to playback
>   methods for the SoundPlayer will not need to reload the .wav file
>   until the path for the sound changes.
>
> **If the .wav file has not been
>   specified or it fails to load, the Play method will play the default
>   beep sound.**

So the problem is that `GetManifestResourceStream()` is not doing what you think it's doing.

**Solution** (based on [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
var thisType        = this.GetType();
var assembly        = thisType.Assembly;
var resourcePath    = string.Format("{0}.{1}", assembly.GetName().Name, thisType.Name);
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourcePath, assembly);
var resourceName    = "SignInSound";

using ( Stream resourceStream = resourceManager.GetStream(resourceName) )
{
    using ( SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(resourceStream) )
    {
        player.PlaySync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the same sound both in Sync and ASync plays.

Comment: Still beep? Is your sound file in the root folder of your project?

Comment: It is in resource folder of the Main file - MainForm.resx

Comment: MissingManifestResourcesException was handeled :((

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "A.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "A" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: Why sad? At least we have some information about the problem now. Exceptions are there to help, not cause frustration.

Comment: How did you add the wav to MainForm.resx? By hand?

Comment: I add it using resource designer -> sounds -> add resource

Comment: FIXED!!! Thanks much!!! The issue was I needed to write "X.MainForm" instead of "MainForm", where X is the name of my solution.

Comment: You could take it 1 step further and retrieve the executing assembly/form name at runtime. See my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `System.Media.SoundPlayer` class has a very limited amount of WAV formats it supports.
I have tried using the string path constructor, and it works with some .wav files, while it fails with others.

Here is some sample code. If you're using Windows 7, you can check it for yourself, just make a default new Windows Forms Application and add one button to it.

Notice how the code works for the "success" string, and throws an InvalidOperationException for the "fail" string.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string success = @"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Battery Critical.wav";
            string fail = @"C:\Windows\Media\Sonata\Windows Battery Critical.wav";
            player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(success);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the file under "success" has a bit rate of 1411 kbps, while the other one has 160 kbps.
Try your code with a WAV file with a bit rate of 1411 kbps and let us know how it works.

Comment: I guess you didn't catch the question.